# Unity test on embedded systems to web output

Tags: c, unit-testing, junit, unity-test-framework

I'm currently working on an embedded device which is able to run unit tests, thanks to the Unity framework. I send the output of these tests into my computer with a JLINK and SEGGER_RTT. Question is, how can i make a web report from unity output?

The best lead I have found, was to transform Unity content to JUnit, in order to have more libraries to work with. Problem is, i didn't find the best approach to have with this JUnit. The idea is to have almost nothing to install, to be able to run tests on a new computer and to have an ergonomic/modern web UI to fastly treat unit tests. The best library i found was Allure (https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2), but I was wondering if it was the best approach (many things to install, and to do before i have anything).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is the point of running unit tests on an embedded device? What is the benefit of doing that? Are you rather talking about some kind of integration test here?

Comment: @GhostCat Running tests is usually considered most worthwhile when done in the environment that the program is to be executed in when in production

Comment: allure 2 supports JUnit.xml test format. Simply download allure2 beta8 https://bintray.com/qameta/generic/allure2 and run `$ allure serve --profile junit junit-output/`

Comment: Also we can consider to support Unity test output format if you link me the docs about it

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Firstly, here is a link to the Unity Github : [link](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity). There is the documentation in the "docs" folder, and some help/utilies in "auto" that may help you. It would be great for many people to have Unity support in Allure.

Secondly, i tried the command line you sent. It works well, it generates an Allure repports, but datas are empty (ALLURE REPORT UNKNOWN). My "junit-output" is a folder with one file (results.xml), with this content : https://pastebin.com/p93iEdWb . Could you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Thomas, have you looked at [Ceedling](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling) (from the same people that make Unity)? Check out the plugins for it https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling/tree/master/plugins some of which allow the format of the test ouptut to be adjusted.

Basically Ceedling provides a Ruby build system for Unity with lots of added features like mock generation and the plugin structure - you only need to use the bits you want though

One of the plugins, gcov, also generates test coverage information, which ceedling can also use to generate a HTML test coverage report similar to below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to work with Ceedling, but as the config file was a little bit complicated to set, i didn't manage to get further at this moment. I'll take a look at your solution later, because it seems really better for an automatic solution.

Comment: I thought the same when I started using it as I'd no previous experience of Ruby or YAML (which ceedling uses), but once I put in a little time to get to grips with it I found it worth the investment. Plus, Mike and the folks are really good at helping out with issues posted on the relevant Github repository if you have problems :-)